# Need to disable auto downloader from site

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Locally, I have developed a music site by means of a WordPress theme, and it's running well. The problem is that once the media file is streaming in the browser, Internet Download Manager(IDM) detects it and generates the download link (That's the nature of IDM) .

So, I want to build my site such that visitors will be able to play and listen to the music, but they are not allowed to download the streaming media by any downloader.

Is there any PHP code, WordPress or jQuery plugin to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically if you're feeding something to the browser, it will also be possible to download it...

Comment: so there is no way to stop 3rd party downloader ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge...

Comment: To listen to the music, the user's browser is already and *has to be* **downloading** it. Saving the data into a file instead of just playing it is a trivial detail.

Comment: Use a flash based music player?

Answer (score 1):

**If you allow visitors to listen to a file, there is no way to prevent them from downloading it. Even DRM is broken if they are determined enough. If they can play it, they can save it.**

That said, you have several options.

1. Use Flash to stream the file.
   It is still pretty easy to download unless the file is embedded in the SWF or uses DRM. This is a common solution, and works well unless you need to support mobile browsers without Flash support.
2. Only allow one download per IP address.
   This has major usability problems and will not work in many browsers. I don't recommend it.
3. Send the file encrypted and decrypt with Javascript.
   Could be very slow, still doesn't stop determined users, depends on Javascript, requires either dataurl support or newer html5 audio apis.
4. Don't worry about it.
   This is what I do.